# install imagecodecs on mac big sur

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

Hi I am trying to install imagecodecs using below and i'm getting this error

```
pip3 install imagecodecs
```

error

```
Collecting imagecodecs
  Using cached imagecodecs-2021.6.8.tar.gz (10.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.1 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from imagecodecs) (1.20.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: imagecodecs
  Building wheel for imagecodecs (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-install-mss5flr3/imagecodecs_d51310f6e51e4fd98d93ac54939ba22a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-install-mss5flr3/imagecodecs_d51310f6e51e4fd98d93ac54939ba22a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-wheel-hcdpa1t2
       cwd: /private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-install-mss5flr3/imagecodecs_d51310f6e51e4fd98d93ac54939ba22a/
  Complete output (96 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
  copying imagecodecs/numcodecs.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
  copying imagecodecs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
  copying imagecodecs/_imagecodecs.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
  copying imagecodecs/imagecodecs.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
  copying imagecodecs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-zfp -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-fastlz -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-postgresql -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libjpeg -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-liblzma -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libmng -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-jpg_0xc3 -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-bzip2 -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libtiff -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-zlib -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-openjpeg -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libjpeg-turbo -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libaivf -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-aom -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-snappy -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-lerc -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-lz4 -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-brunsli -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-dav1d -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-giflib -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-highway -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-rav1e -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libdeflate -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-zopfli -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-cfitsio -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-zstd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-bitshuffle -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-liblj92 -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-charls -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-brotli -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libwebp -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libaec -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/PATENTS-rav1e -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-zlib-ng -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libpng -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-jpeg -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-lcms2 -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-blosc -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-lzf -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-jxrlib -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-jpeg-xl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
  running build_ext
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_aec.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_bitshuffle.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_blosc.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_brotli.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_bz2.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_deflate.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_gif.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_imcd.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_jpeg2k.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_jpeg8.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_jpegsof3.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_jpegxr.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_ljpeg.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_lz4.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_lzf.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_lzma.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_pglz.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_png.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_rcomp.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_shared.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_snappy.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_tiff.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_webp.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_zlib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_zopfli.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  skipping 'imagecodecs/_zstd.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  building 'imagecodecs._aec' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9
  creating build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -stdlib=libc++ -Iimagecodecs -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imagecodecs/_aec.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/_aec.o
  In file included from imagecodecs/_aec.c:612:
  In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
  In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
  In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1944:
  /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
  #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
   ^
  imagecodecs/_aec.c:619:10: fatal error: 'libaec.h' file not found
  #include "libaec.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~
  1 warning and 1 error generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for imagecodecs
  Running setup.py clean for imagecodecs
Failed to build imagecodecs
Installing collected packages: imagecodecs
    Running setup.py install for imagecodecs ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-install-mss5flr3/imagecodecs_d51310f6e51e4fd98d93ac54939ba22a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-install-mss5flr3/imagecodecs_d51310f6e51e4fd98d93ac54939ba22a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-record-8prj5e1w/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/homebrew/include/python3.9/imagecodecs
         cwd: /private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-install-mss5flr3/imagecodecs_d51310f6e51e4fd98d93ac54939ba22a/
    Complete output (96 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
    copying imagecodecs/numcodecs.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
    copying imagecodecs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
    copying imagecodecs/_imagecodecs.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
    copying imagecodecs/imagecodecs.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
    copying imagecodecs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-zfp -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-fastlz -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-postgresql -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libjpeg -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-liblzma -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libmng -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-jpg_0xc3 -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-bzip2 -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libtiff -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-zlib -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-openjpeg -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libjpeg-turbo -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libaivf -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-aom -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-snappy -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-lerc -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-lz4 -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-brunsli -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-dav1d -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-giflib -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-highway -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-rav1e -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libdeflate -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-zopfli -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-cfitsio -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-zstd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-bitshuffle -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-liblj92 -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-charls -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-brotli -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libwebp -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libaec -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/PATENTS-rav1e -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-zlib-ng -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-libpng -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-jpeg -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-lcms2 -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-blosc -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-lzf -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-jxrlib -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    copying imagecodecs/licenses/LICENSE-jpeg-xl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/licenses
    running build_ext
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_aec.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_bitshuffle.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_blosc.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_brotli.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_bz2.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_deflate.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_gif.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_imcd.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_jpeg2k.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_jpeg8.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_jpegsof3.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_jpegxr.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_ljpeg.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_lz4.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_lzf.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_lzma.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_pglz.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_png.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_rcomp.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_shared.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_snappy.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_tiff.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_webp.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_zlib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_zopfli.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    skipping 'imagecodecs/_zstd.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'imagecodecs._aec' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9
    creating build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -stdlib=libc++ -Iimagecodecs -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c imagecodecs/_aec.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/imagecodecs/_aec.o
    In file included from imagecodecs/_aec.c:612:
    In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
    In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
    In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1944:
    /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
    #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
     ^
    imagecodecs/_aec.c:619:10: fatal error: 'libaec.h' file not found
    #include "libaec.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-install-mss5flr3/imagecodecs_d51310f6e51e4fd98d93ac54939ba22a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-install-mss5flr3/imagecodecs_d51310f6e51e4fd98d93ac54939ba22a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/rz/qppsg_1n2v1grhg095ldbpgm0000gn/T/pip-record-8prj5e1w/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/homebrew/include/python3.9/imagecodecs Check the logs for full command output.
```

can you pls help with this
i have tried installing dependencies but not able to install it,
i have tried with conda also, but it installs the package and when i run requirement.text , it shows the error, im using docker with ubuntu as base image

Comment: [Conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/imagecodecs) has osx-arm64 binaries. MacPorts and PyPI don't.

Comment: yeah, so can you please tell how i install imagecodecs

Answer (score 0):

The current advice ([issue/6](https://github.com/cgohlke/imagecodecs/issues/6), [issue/17](https://github.com/cgohlke/imagecodecs/issues/17)) by the author is to install older versions:

```
pip install imagecodecs==2021.4.28
```

Comment: Hi i tried this but i get below error
`



#10 12.88 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement imagecodecs==2020.5.30 (from versions: 2018.10.10, 2018.10.17, 2018.10.18, 2018.10.21, 2018.10.22, 2018.10.28, 2018.10.30, 2018.11.8, 2018.12.1, 2018.12.12, 2018.12.16, 2019.1.1, 2019.1.14, 2019.1.20, 2019.2.2, 2019.2.20, 2019.2.22, 2019.4.20, 2019.5.22, 2019.11.5, 2019.11.18, 2019.11.28, 2019.12.3, 2019.12.10, 2019.12.16, 2019.12.31, 2020.1.31, 2020.2.18, 2020.5.30)
#10 12.88 ERROR: No matching distribution found for imagecodecs==2020.5.30


`

Comment: This generates the same error for me.

Answer (score -3):

try `conda install -c conda-forge imagecodecs`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).